# Meaning of 'make out' in " . . . you didn't, somehow, make out to give us the thing straight"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVIII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_18)

Passage 281

> I was but a little way down the street, when I was arrested by the sound of some one running, and Jim's voice calling me by name. He had followed me with a letter which had been long awaiting my return.
>
> I took it in a dream. “This has been a devil of a business,” said I.
>
> “Don't think hard of Mamie,” he pleaded. “It's the way she's made; it's her high-toned loyalty. And of course I know it's all right. **I know your sterling character; but you didn't, somehow, make out to give us the thing straight**, Loudon. Anybody might have—I mean it—I mean——”
>
> “Never mind what you mean, my poor Jim,” said I. “She's a gallant little woman and a loyal wife: and I thought her splendid. My story was as fishy as the devil. I'll never think the less of either her or you.”
>
> “It'll blow over; it must blow over,” said he.
>
> “It never can,” I returned, sighing: “and don't you try to make it! Don't name me, unless it's with an oath. And get home to her right away. Good-bye, my best of friends. Good-bye, and God bless you. We shall never meet again.”
>
> “Oh Loudon, that we should live to say such words!” he cried.

The phrasal verb 'make out' troubles me there. I take it to mean 'succeed' in this context but I'm not sure.

**Merriam-Webster** has this: [link2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20out), [link3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succeed#kidsdictionary)

> make out (verb): Kids Definition
>
> 5 : SUCCEED sense 2
>
> *make out well in business*
>
> succeed (verb):
>
> 2a: to turn out well
>
> 2b: to reach a desired end or object : be successful

**Wiktionary, The free dictionary** has this: [link4](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_out)

> 4.(now chiefly US, regional, intransitive) To manage, get along; to do (well, badly etc.). [from 17th c.]
>
> *Oh, you were on a TV game show? How did you make out?*

**OED** has this: [link5](https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/Meanings?textTermText0=make%20out&textTermOpt0=WordPhrase)

> to make out, in make, v.¹
>
> transitive. To succeed in accomplishing; to effect, achieve. Now regional exc. colloquial in to make it out: to make shift, get along. See also…
>
> transitive. With infinitive as object. To manage, make shift. Also (occasionally) with impersonal subject, as the weather. Now chiefly U.S. regional.
>
> intransitive. colloquial. To make shift, get along; to succeed, thrive; to get on (well, badly, etc.).

We have to consider both *Jim Pinkerton* and *Loudon Dodd* are American.
What does 'make out' mean in this context?

Comment: Obsolete, regional or dialect usage. From the context I would suggest 'contrive', 'manage', or 'succeed'.

Comment: The full OED **make out** phrasal verb definition I.3 (transitive) *To **represent** or delineate clearly or in detail. Also of a thing: to form the figure of. **Obsolete***  OR III.9.a. *To succeed in accomplishing; to effect, achieve. Now **regional** exc. colloquial in to make it out: to make shift, get along.*

Comment: Several times now, I have cited links to 19th century dictionaries available online and downloadable as PDFs. Why do you continue to consult contemporary dictionaries on these questions relating to *The Wrecker*?  Dictionaries with a contemporary focus are often not going to tell you about things that have fallen out of use.

Comment: I mean no harm - my first version with only one source was makeshift :).

Comment: It's not that you need more than one source. You need to use a 19th c, dictionary like Websters, as it will have usages no longer current and often missing from 21st c. dictionaries, not even listed there as *obsolete*; is has the added advantage that it's available online at no charge as a PDF and is not behind a pay-wall.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. First I am looking up the contemporary usage and then the prior one.

Comment: This Imperial Dictionary by John Ogilvie is great help. Once again, thank you very much indeed :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here **make out to [verb]** is synonymous with the contemporary **manage to [verb]**.

> .. to succeed and no more; to have success at last as *He made out to reconcile the contending parties*.

John Ogilvie *[The Imperial Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Imperial_dictionary_on_the_basis_of/oHwCAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22make%20out%20to%22&pg=PA104&printsec=frontcover): NEW EDITION,
CAREFULLY REVISED AND GREATLY AUGMENTED.
EDITED BY
CHARLES ANNANDALE, M.A.* (London, 1883)